# how to merge columns in a for loop?

Tags: r, for-loop, paste

I have a small problem, when trying to combine columns using paste, I combine the first column and the last result of the for loop. Tell me how to combine all the results of the for loop, and not just the last one?

```
if(i==1 | j==2){
                common.res <- data.table(res[,3])
                f <- data.table(paste(common.res1[,1],common.res[,]))
            }
```

My data:

| x1 | x2 | x3 |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 20 | 30 | 40 |
| 20 | 30 | 40 |
| 20 | 30 | 40 |

What do I get after I fasten the columns in the loop:

| x1 |
| --- |
| 20 40 |
| 20 40 |
| 20 40 |

What I want to get:

| x1 |
| --- |
| 20 30 40 |
| 20 30 40 |
| 20 30 40 |

Comment: `do.call(paste, your_data_table)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do this without a for loop using `tidyr::unite()`:

```
library(tidyr)

res %>% unite(col = 'name_for_new_col', sep = ' ')
```

This will paste together all columns in `res` and put a space between each element. If you want to specify particular columns to do this on you can instead say:

```
res %>% unite(col = 'name_for_new_col', x1:x3, sep = ' ')
```

If you want to keep the old columns as well you can specify `remove = FALSE` within `unite()`.

---

Alternatively, you can do it in base R using `apply` and `paste`:

```
res2 <- as.data.frame(apply(res, 1, paste, collapse = ' '))
names(res2)[1] <- 'nicer.name' #rename the single column
```

Or with just `paste` and a `for loop`:

```
df = data.frame(matrix(nrow = nrow(res), ncol = 1))
for (i in 1:nrow(res)) {
df[i,1] <- (paste(res[i,], collapse = ' '))
}
```